# Organisation graph

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to build something like this with `css/bootstrap`: 
[image]

The requirement is a list that will be displayed like this, like circles/squares connected with zigzag lines. I need some `css` tricks on how to achieve this effect so it looks more visually appealing.

Thanks.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: try d3 examples

Comment: http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/

Comment: Please try and search for the same on google. I found one ine one of top links.
https://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE